# Weird comparison in ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash

I am looking at `~/.bashrc` file on Arch-based system and I see a line that I do not understand

```
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true
```

Can someone explain or point me to bash documentation which goes into details about this comparison as I don't have a clue about it.

In case it matters here is an excerpt which shows how `safe_term` and `match_lhs` are defined

```
use_color=false

# Set colorful PS1 only on colorful terminals.
# dircolors --print-database uses its own built-in database
# instead of using /etc/DIR_COLORS.  Try to use the external file
# first to take advantage of user additions.  Use internal bash
# globbing instead of external grep binary.
safe_term=${TERM//[^[:alnum:]]/?}   # sanitize TERM
match_lhs=""
[[ -f ~/.dir_colors   ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(<~/.dir_colors)"
[[ -f /etc/DIR_COLORS ]] && match_lhs="${match_lhs}$(</etc/DIR_COLORS)"
[[ -z ${match_lhs}    ]] \
    && type -P dircolors >/dev/null \
    && match_lhs=$(dircolors --print-database)
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] && use_color=true
```

Comment: The right hand side of `==` in `[[ ... ]]` is a pattern, same as a glob. `*` stands for "anything".

Comment: Can you check what you have in `~/.dir_colors`, and `/etc/DIR_COLORS` (the two files that script uses to fill `match_lhs`), and what `dircolors --print-database` prints for you? Because I'm curious if indeed it has wildcards there and not just static strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]]
```

Taking that apart, `[[ string == pattern ]]` is a string comparison against a pattern match, and in the pattern `*` means "anything". On the right hand side, `$'\n'` is a newline, `TERM`  just a fixed string, and `${safe_term}` gives the contents of the variable. So, if `${safe_term}` contains e.g. `xterm`, it will look for the string `<newline>TERM xterm`, with anything before or after it. On the left, there's a newline again, and whatever `${match_lhs}` contains.

Now, `${match_lhs}` is set to what `dircolors --print-database` outputs, and that contains lines like this:

```
TERM Eterm
TERM ansi
TERM *color*
...
```

Actually, it tries to read the two config files first, but I just assume they're supposed to contain similar entries.

`${safe_term}` comes from the value of `$TERM`, only with some cleaning up (some lines before).

So, in effect, it tests to see if the current terminal type in `$TERM` is contained in the known terminal types listed by `dircolors`.

The newlines are there to anchor the match to the start of the line, and the extra newline on the left-hand side is for the case of a match at the very first line (which wouldn't have newline before it otherwise).

---

What's confusing here is that at least on my system, the output of `dircolors --print-database` includes lines like `TERM *color*`, `TERM con[0-9]*x[0-9]*` and `TERM xterm*`. While those are valid patterns, it would seem to me that the script here wouldn't use them as patterns, since it puts them on the *left* side of `[[ str == pattern ]]`. Either I've understood this wrong, or the script author has a made a mistake.